# Pass a variable as an attribute to an HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, button

Let's say I have defined a variable in Javascript: var user_name = "John Doe". Now I want the following button to display this variable's contents in place of "user_name":

```
    <input class="button" value= "user_name" />
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Which input(s) would you want to select if there are multiple on a page?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').value = 'John Doe'
```

You will have to add an `id` in your input though:

```
<input id="myButton" class="button" value= "user_name" />
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxVCy/)**

Comment: What do I put in the value attribute of the input tag?

Comment: @user2174597 Um... 'John Doe'? What do you mean?

Comment: @user2174597 Well if you're changing it immediately it doesn't matter

Comment: @user2174597 Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: @user2174597 Well you're going to have to be a bit more specific than that. Did you make sure the DOM was loaded before you execute the JS? I put together a [fiddle (here is a link)](http://jsfiddle.net/qxVCy/) and it worked perfectly...

Comment: Yes that's fine. Answer me this : Is the document.getelementbyid statement to be placed in the js?

Comment: @user2174597 Um... where else would you put JavaScript?

Comment: It was just a confirmation.. Meanwhile il try out the link.

Comment: @user2174597 You mean in the JSFiddle?

Comment: No No. I did exactly what you showed in the fiddle. Fiddle's working fine. Its my code that's giving problems. I would have posted an image but my rep score doesnt allow me. Just imagine a blank button and that's what's happening to my output.

Comment: @user2174597 Did you make sure the DOM was loaded?

Comment: @user2174597 As in `window.onload`

Comment: No I dont know about this. How should I proceed now?

Comment: @user2174597 Um... learn JavaScript at a website that teaches you?

Comment: I don't have much time for that. I've to give this in by tomorrow. These are some final touches i'm giving to my page. Would really appreciate if you gave me a link about DOM.

Comment: @user2174597 you could just do `window.onload = function() { /* do your stuff */ }`